# Consultas sobres Arrays en MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Tengo la siguiente **base de datos**

```
[
    {
        "codpeli": 1,
        "titol": "La La Land",
        "sinopsi": "Mia (Emma Stone), una solitaria aspirante a actriz y Sebastian (Ryan Gosling), un carismático aspirante a pianista de jazz, se enamoran en la ciudad de Los Angeles, una ciudad que les ha dado el amor, pero que también puede arrebatárselo. En una competición constante por buscar un hueco en el mundo del espectáculo, Mia y Sebastian descubren que el equilibrio entre el amor y el arte puede ser el mayor obstáculo de todos. ",
        "dvds": [2, 1, 3],
        "numprestecs": 2,
        "prestecs": [
            { "dataPres": ISODate("2017-05-28T11:32:18Z"), "coddvd": 3, "soci": "Maria", "dataDev": ISODate("2017-05-29T15:32:11Z") },
            { "dataPres": ISODate("2017-05-30T13:52:28Z"), "coddvd": 1, "soci": "Jordi" },
            { "dataPres": ISODate("2017-05-31T11:32:18Z"), "coddvd": 3, "soci": "Arnau" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "codpeli" : 2,
        "titol": "Figuras ocultas",
        "sinopsi": "Narra la historia nunca contada de tres brillantes mujeres científicas afroamericanas que trabajaron en la NASA a comienzos de los años sesenta (en plena carrera espacial, y asimismo en mitad de la lucha por los derechos civiles de los negros estadounidenses) en el ambicioso proyecto de poner en órbita al astronauta John Glenn.",
        "dvds": [5, 4],
        "numprestecs": 1,
        "prestecs": [ 
            { "dataPres": ISODate("2017-05-30T23:32:18Z"), "coddvd": 5, "soci": "Maria" }
        ]
    }
]
```

Necesito listar **las prestaciones**(prestec) que no han sido devueltas (que no tengan el campo 'dataDev')de la pelicula La La Land.

Realizo la consulta, pero solo me muestra la primera(la número 1),cuando me deberían listar dos prestaciones :

```
db.videoclub.find(
            {
                titol : "La La Land",
                prestecs: { $elemMatch: { dataDev: { $exists : 0 }}}
            },
            {
                _id : 0,
                titol : 1,
                "prestecs.$" : 1
            }
        ).pretty()
```

results :

```
{
    "titol" : "La La Land",
    "prestecs" : [
        {
            "dataPres" : ISODate("2017-05-30T13:52:28Z"),
            "coddvd" : 1,
            "soci" : "Jordi"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `aggregate()` hacer `$match` primero por `titol` y luego `$unwind` para explotar el array y poder volver a hacer `$match` sobre `prestects.dataDev`.

Luego puedes rearmar el array interno con un `$group` y finalmente `$project` para mostrar los keys que necesites:

```
db.videoclub.aggregate(
    { $match: { titol: "La La Land" } }, // Solo los que tienen titol "La La Land"
    { $unwind: "$prestecs" }, // "Aplana" el array "prestecs" 
    { $match: { "prestecs.dataDev": { $exists: 0 } } }, // Solo los que no tienen el campo prestecs.dataDev  
    { $group: { _id: "$titol", prestecs: { $addToSet: "$prestecs" } } }, //reagreupa el array prestecs
    { $project: { _id: 0, titol: "$_id", prestecs: "$prestecs" } } // Oculta el id y muestra titol y prestecs
).pretty()
```

Este es el resultado obtenido

```
{
    "titol" : "La La Land",
    "prestecs" : [
        {
            "dataPres" : ISODate("2017-05-31T11:32:18Z"),
            "coddvd" : 3,
            "soci" : "Arnau"
        },
        {
            "dataPres" : ISODate("2017-05-30T13:52:28Z"),
            "coddvd" : 1,
            "soci" : "Jordi"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tood Ok!
una última consulta, y si quisiera ordenarlo por dataPres o coddvd??